# read creation date from file name and change - batch

Tags: macos, bash

I have files that are named like "clip-2014-01-31 18;50;15.mp4", i.e. "clip-YYYY-MM-DD hh;mm;ss.mp4".

How can I set the creation date and time according to how it is specified  in the file name for all 2000 files I have in a folder. I know the command `touch -t` changes the creation date, but I do not know how to extract the date/time information from the file name and put this into a command so this is done automatically for all files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're lucky because the numbers in your file names are in just the order `touch -t` needs.

This command in the terminal will work. You just need to make sure your working directory is set to the folder you want to do:

```
for f in *; do
    t=$(echo $f | sed -E 's/([A-z]*-)|([ ,;])|(\..*)//g' | sed -E 's/(.*)(..)/\1.\2/')
    touch -t $t "$f"
done
```

To break it down:

`for f in *` sets the variable `f` to the name of each file in the directory, in turn.

`do` puts everything until the `done` into the `for` loop.

`t=$(…)` sets the variable `t` to the output of the commands in the parentheses.

The first `sed` command matches any letters before a `-` symbol, the `-` `;` and the `space` symbols, and the file extension, and deletes them.

The second `sed` command inserts a period between the mm and ss values, as touch requires.

`touch -t $t $f` changes the file modification and creation times to the value of `t` on the file `f`.

Tested on some dummy files with whatever version of `sed` ships with Mavericks.

Comment: @mcanwo please can you mark this answer as accepted. It helps reward the responder and also notes this question as having a working solution: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work